# how can i show the product category name dynamically on the category page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I can't find the answer to this anywhere

I would like to place some text on the product category pages, above the products that say this

Browse All The **** Products Listed On our site

where **** is the category name of the page

so for example

when a visitor is looking at the "Art" category page the text would read

Browse All The Art Products Listed On our site

I have been able to get a generic text to show, by using the code below that I found online

I added this code to my themes functions.php file

```
//Add Category Description Automatically

add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 
'ts_add_to_category_description' );
function ts_add_to_category_description() {
if ( is_product_category()) {
   echo '<center><span style="color:#e48143;"><p>Browse All The Products 
listed On our site</p></span></center>';
}
}
```

this works well and shows "Browse All The Products Listed On our site" on all the category pages, but I have no idea how I would pull in the category name

any help would be fantastic, I'm sorry if the terminology is wrong, I'm very new to coding

Steve

Answer (score 0):

i managed to sort it, with your help by using this code

```
//Add Category Description Automatically
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'ts_add_to_category_description' );
function ts_add_to_category_description() {
if ( is_product_category()) { 
echo 'Browse All The ';
echo single_cat_title();
echo ' Listed ';
}
}
```

I'm not sure if it's very graceful but it appears to render correctly

Thank you so much for the heads up,

Steve